# Add column values when another value is the same SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table EMPLOYEES with the following columns:

- DEPARTMENT_ID
- SALARY

How would i write a query to add all salaries if they have the same department id, without explicitly stating what the department id is?

Comment: SELECT SUM(SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEES GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID

Answer (score 1):

This will display a single column where each cell is the sum of salaries of a given department.

```
select sum(salary) 
from employees 
group by department_id;
```

Or if the department names are stored in another table, called DEPARTMENT, having columns ID and NAME, and you want to display them as well :

```
select dep.name, sum(emp.salary) 
from employees emp
join departments dep on dep.id = emp.department_id
group by dep.name
```

Comment: what if the department_name is in another table, how could i combine the 2 in 1 query?

Comment: @JoeG : then you have to JOIN with the department table - edited my answer for that use case

Comment: I tried SELECT
  DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENT_NAME, SUM(EMPLOYEES.SALARY) 
FROM 
  EMPLOYEES
JOIN 
  DEPARTMENTS 
ON 
  DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID = EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID
GROUP BY
  DEPARTMENT_NAME; getting this error   ORA-00904: "DEPARTMENT"."DEPARTMENT_NAME": invalid identifier

Comment: @JoeG Where is the alias name for the tables?  Please have a look at the answer provided by @GMB; it does have the alias names.